# Bitbucket Urls using user name

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

When I clone my bitbucket git repository using sourcetree, the URL includes my user name.

When my co-worker does the clone, the URL uses her user name.

for example

https://myusername@bitbucket.org/ourteamname/ourrepositoryname.git
   https://herusername@bitbucket.org/ourteamname/ourrepositoryname.git

both resolve to

```
https://bitbucket.org/ourteamname/ourrepositoryname.git
```

When I go to either URL in the browser they both resolve to a different bit bucket URL.

Until I realized this was what was happening, I found the user name in the URL to be very confusing.   Why is it done this way?

Comment: Can you provide examples for the URL's you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone URLs can have two different usernames in them: one for the user connecting (the username between `https://` and `@bitbucket.org`), and one for the repo's owner (the username between `bitbucket.org` and the repo name).

The repo owner is included in the repo URL to distinguish between, say, `https://bitbucket.org/mirror/linux` and `https://bitbucket.org/some-random-user/linux`, which could be completely unrelated.